# how to express $c(n,2)$ in terms of harmonic number

Tags: combinatorics

how to express $c(n,2)$ in terms of harmonic number,where $c(n,2)$ is stirling number ?
I know the answer is $(n-1)!H_{n-1}$,but could anybody explain it to me in details?Thanks pretty much

Answer (score 1):

The rising factorial is defined by the formula and their relation to the Stirling numbers is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x)^{(n)} =x(x+1) \cdots (x+n-1) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} s(n,k) x^k .
\end{eqnarray*}
From this it is easy to see $s(n,1)= (n-1)!$. For $k=2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
s(n,2) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \underbrace{(j-1)(j+1)}_{ \text{miss the j term}} \cdots (n-1) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now factor off $(n-1)!$ and you will have the result.

Comment: Is there any combinatorial proof?

Comment: See this question for another formula relating to $s(n,2)$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503049/proof-concerning-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind ... Jack also gives some fascinating formulae relating to their generating functions.